# CSS rotate relative to current position

Tags: css, transform

I have a spinning wheel graphic which is set to rotate infinitely from 0 to 360 degrees.

I then want to spin that element in the reverse direction by a fixed amount each time rather than to a specific position relative to it's 0 degree position.

Put another way, this is what happens now:

```
Wheel is at 5 degrees
Wheel is reset
Wheel moves 5 degrees back to 0

Wheel is at 270 degrees
Wheel is reset
Wheel moves 270 degrees back to 0
```

And what I want is a consistent movement:

```
Wheel is at 5 degrees
Wheel is reset
Wheel moves 180 degrees back

Wheel is at 270 degrees
Wheel is reset
Wheel moves 180 degrees back
```

Any suggestions?

We're using the Bourbon.io SASS library so the SASS code looks like this:

```
.spin {
    @include animation(spin 3.0s linear infinite);
}

@include keyframes(spin) {
    from {
            @include transform(rotate(0deg));
    }
    to {
            @include transform(rotate(360deg)); 
    }
}

.spin-back {
    @include animation(spinBack 3.0s linear infinite);
}

@include keyframes(spinBack) {
    to {
            @include transform(rotate(0deg)); 
    }
}
```

The classes spin and spin-back are toggled on click via script.

Comment: post your code please!

Comment: @web-tiki, code added!

Comment: This is not possible with pure CSS as far as I know.

Comment: @Andrei that was my thought. We could have a timer running on a script that we could interrogate on click and work out how far round the transition has gone based on the transition speed, but I suspect that's going to get clunky

Comment: How many of those `.spin` animations you want to run at the same time?

Comment: @Andrei 4 at present, but possibly more. It's a responsive site so mobile is very much in mind.

Comment: Did you manage to find a clean solution?